# Arduino Yun WifiStatus Example Failing

Tags: arduino, wifi, arduino-yun

I am able to connect and upload the WifiStatus example per the instructions on the Arduino Site/Examples/Yun. However, when I hit the serial monitor button it is supposed to print out the relevant Wifi stats, instead it says "unable to connect" and the final line goes a bit further..."unable to connect: is the sketch using the bridge".  Any ideas?  A post suggested reseting the 32U4, which I did, but no luck.

Incidently, all of this is over Wifi. Board and port are set per instructions. Yun pings fine and receives the uploaded sketch fine.

Answer (score 0):

More code is usually more illuminating... so you might get better answers when you provide more information.

"is the sketch using the bridge" seems to indicate that there is some problem with the Bridge library. Is it being initialized? Did initialization (i.e., "Bridge.begin()" succeed?

Comment: I have the same issue. My code is the same as the one given by arduino in its examples (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunWiFiStatus).

Bridge.begin() is part of setup(). How can I know if it succeeded or not?

Comment: @AlexisEggermont With Arduino, you're back to console debugging: After every suspicious step, print results using Serial.println().

Answer (score 0):

A sketch with bridge functional and serial monitor via network connection cannot be running simultaneously as they use the same hardware connection.

You may use the serial monitor via USB port, or Serial TX/RX pins, or  SoftwareSerial for this.